# Node.js Не происходит Redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post, express

Добрый день.
Есть страница вида:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/register">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div id="alert-msg"></div>
  <button type="button"  onclick="login()" class="btn btn-default">Вход</button>
</form>
        <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

JS выглядит так:

```
function login(){
   var email = $('#email').val();
   var password = $('#password').val();
   $.post('/login',{ email: email, password: password }, function(data){
        if(data.success){
              document.location.href = '/pvt/lenta';
        }else if(data.error){
              $("#alert-msg").toggleClass("alert alert-danger").html("Введены некорректные данные!");
        }
   });
}
```

На стороне сервера есть такой код:

```js
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
        if (req.session.user) return res.redirect('/pvt/profile');
        
        api.checkUser(req.body)
  .then(function(user){
   if(user){
    req.session.user = {id: user._id, name: user.email}
    res.send({ success: "Logged in" });
   } else {
    res.send({ error: "Incorrect credits" });
   }
  })
  .catch(function(error){
   return next(error)
  })
});

app.get('/pvt/profile', function(req, res){
        res.render('../tpl/lenta.ejs')
});
```

Пользователь залогинен, т.е. присутствует в req.session.user. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку вход, ничего не проиходит. Т.е. редирект не срабатывает. Когда делаю console.log(data) мне выводится содержимое файла lenta.ejs.
Как мне осуществить корректно редирект?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам. Надо было убрать return перед res.redirect

Comment: Решение еще более странное чем проблема